# Why isn't Python switching from enclosing to local variable scope?

Tags: python, scope

I was just checking my mental model about scoping in Python and got confused. The first two examples match my model, the 3rd example doesn't.

I assumed that Python has 4 scopes:

- Local
- Enclosed
- Global
- Built-in

I imagine those 4 scopes like dictionaries. The built-in one is pre-defined and the other ones get generated after some actions:

- Global: The main script file creates a variable. This scope is killed once the script finished executing.
- Local: Within a function, a variable is called. This scope is killed once the function finished executing
- Enclosed: A function `B` is defined within a function `A`. Once `B` is called, the local scope of `A` becomes the enclosed scope of `B`. This scope is killed once `B` finished executing.

I assumed that Python has those 4 dictionaries in memory and essentially tries every time all 4:

1. Does the variable exist in local scope? Use it. If not, got to 2
2. Does the variable exist in enclosed scope? Use it. If not, go to 3.
3. Does the variable exist in global scope? Use it. If not, go to 4.
4. does the variable exist in the built-ins? Use it. If not, throw a `NameError`

I especially assumed that a variable could switch from enclosed scope being used to local scope being used. This is obviously not the case. Could somebody explain why? Is there maybe a bigger difference in my mental model from what actually happens?

### Example 1

This prints "local"

```py
def foo():
    min = lambda n: "enclosing"

    def bar():
        """Bar is enclosed by 'foo'"""
        min = lambda n: "local"
        print(min([1, 2, 3]))

    bar()


foo()
```

### Example 2

This prints "enclosing"

```py
def foo():
    min = lambda n: "enclosing"

    def bar():
        """Bar is enclosed by 'foo'"""
        print(min([1,2,3]))

    bar()


foo()
```

### Example 3

```py
def foo():
    min = lambda n: "enclosing"

    def bar():
        """Bar is enclosed by 'foo'"""
        print(min([1,2,3]))
        min = lambda n: "local"
        print(min([1, 2, 3]))

    bar()


foo()
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 13, in <module>
    foo()
  File "example.py", line 10, in foo
    bar()
  File "example.py", line 6, in bar
    print(min([1,2,3]))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: I've also noticed that `def x(): y` gives an `NameError`, but `def x(): y; y = 1` gives an `UnboundLocalError`. Meaning code AFTER the error can influence the error. I'm not sure if this is another problem with my mental model or the same.

Comment: The only one of your fallbacks that can happen at runtime is global -> builtins.  The categorization of a variable as local, nonlocal (what you're calling "enclosed"), or global is made entirely at compile time;  basically, any variable that you assign to (anywhere in the function) becomes local in the absence of an explicit `global` or `nonlocal` declaration in that function.

Comment: @jasonharper If you make that comment an answer, I'll accept it. If you add more details about how Python executes stuff (what happens at compile time, what at runtime), I'll +1 (or +50) is :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that if you assign to a variable anywhere inside the body of a function, the variable is considered local - in the whole function.

If you want to refer to a global variable, you have to say so explicitely by declaring

```
global my_variable
```

and if you mean to refer to the variable in the closest enclosing scope that defines it, you have do declare it as

```
nonlocal my_variable
```

So, there is nothing special happening here: the general rule for deciding that a variable is local still applies.